# Starting index at zero

Tags: list-manipulation

In order to start an index at zero, I found [N. Abbasi](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/using_zero_index_in_Mathematica/index.htm) is quite convenient. For instance,

[image]

(Note that in the original code by Abbasi, one of under scores _ in Notation[] was missing.)

However, with this method, we need to define these notations for each symbol.
I'd like to use any symbols with subscripts, like "a" in the above pic. with the same definition.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [Starting tensor indices at 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087854/starting-tensor-indices-at-0)  for a more complete discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the useful info.

Answer (score 20):

There's no need to use the `Notation` package to achieve the same behavior. For example:

```
SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst];
Subscript[a_, i_Integer?NonNegative] := a[[i+1]]
```

Then:

```
a = {"Alice", "Bob"};
Subscript[a, 0]
Subscript[a, 1]
```

> "Alice"
>
> "Bob"

or an image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer solved this perfectly! Hope this to be convenient for many users.